# In this sentence what it means (on his record)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Democratic presidential contenders got their first chance to confront
>   Mike Bloomberg on the debate stage Wednesday night in Las Vegas.
>   Bloomberg spent much of the night on the defensive as the five other
>   candidates repeatedly **pressed the billionaire on his record**. CBS News
>   political contributor Molly Hooper joins Anne-Marie Green and Vladimir
>   Duthiers in the CBSN studio to break down the debate.

In this sentence what is it means (on his record) ?

Comment: "pressed" means "questioned." And "record" means "known history." So "pressed him on his record" means he was asked difficult questions about his past. As it says, Bloomberg was confronted and that is why he was "on the defensive."